# Calculations for building a mixer circuit

Tags: summing

I have been tasked with building a mixer.

\$V(output) = 1/2*V1 + 1/6*V2\$

Thinking in terms of [superposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superposition_principle), I assume I can hook up \$V1\$ and \$V2\$ to the circuit separately, and then sum the results up to achieve \$V(output)\$.

1. I start by connecting the circuit to V1 and ground, and add two equal resistors to each side of the output. Since the resistors are equal, V splits in half, and the first half of the task is done.
2. I replace V1 with ground, and hook up V2 to where ground was. I change the relationship between resistors from \$1:1\$ to \$1:5\$ to get the 1/6 relationship. \$1/(1+5)\$.

But now I don't understand how to proceed. I can't simply add the values of the resistors together, as that will yield neither of the right relationships. Please note that this question is tagged with [homework](/questions/tagged/homework).

Comment: What's requested is not a mixer but a summer, with different scaling for each of the inputs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be possible to do this with 3 resistors:

[image]

The gain from V1 to OUT is a resistor divider with R1 as the top leg and the parallel combination of R2 and R3 as the bottom leg:

G1 = (R2//R3) / (R1 + R2//R3) = 1/2

Similarly, you can write the equation for the gain from V2 to the output:

G2 = (R1//R3) / (R2 + R1//R3) = 1/6

Now you have two equations and three unknowns.  That should tell you the problem is underconstrained.  With a little thought you should realize that if you have one set of resistors that meet the requirements, you can easily find others by multiplying all the resistors by the same constant.  In other words, all that matters is the *ratio* of the resistors as the problem is stated.  The absolute value effects apparent impedances, but those weren't specified.

To get the third constraint, you can simply pick a fixed value for one of the resistors.  For example, decide R3 is 1 Ω, then solve for the remaining two values.  If you later decided you would rather R3 were 1 kΩ, then you can multiply all the values by 1k.

So the third equation is:

R3 = 1 kΩ

Now you have three independent equations and three unknowns.  The rest is simple algebra.  This is your problem, so I'll leave that as a exercise for you.